# Why repeating a pd.series does not work as expected?

Tags: python, pandas

I have just started working with python 3.7 and I am trying to create a series e.g from 0 to 23 and repeat it. Using

```
rep1 = pd.Series(range(24))
```

I figured out how to make the first 24 values and I wanted to "copy-paste" it many times so that the final series is the original 5 times, one after the other. The result with `rep = pd.Series.repeat(rep1, 5)` gives me a result that looks like this and it's not what I want

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

What I seek for is the 0-23 range multiple times. Any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understood you right, but something like this maybe?
```rep1 = pd.Series(list(range(24))*5)```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it worked. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
pd.concat([rep1]*5)
```

This will repeat your series 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np

rep = pd.Series(np.tile(rep1, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list to generate directly your Series.

```
rep = pd.Series(list(range(24))*5)
```

Comment: Yes, but only with Python 2.7.

Comment: Correct, it works only with ```list()``` in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the repeated Series as one data object then use a pandas DataFrame for this. A DataFrame is multiple pandas Series in one object, sharing an index.

So firstly I am creating a python list, of 0-23, 5 times.

Then I put this into a DataFrame and optionally transpose so that I have the rows going down rather than across in this example.

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [list(range(0,24))] * 5
rep = pd.DataFrame(lst).transpose()
```

[image]